# Lightbox em imagens

Tags: novo-recurso, imagem

[Nesta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63720/buscar-email-na-base-de-dados-atrav%C3%A9s-do-nome), o autor da pergunta colocou várias imagens para exemplificar os protótipos de tela, e que são restritas pela largura, ajustando a altura proporcionalmente. O problema é que, para monitores pequenos, preciso pedir para abrir a imagem em uma outra aba para poder ler o que a imagem diz.

Seria possível instalar um recurso de *Lightbox* em que eu possa simplesmente clicar em uma imagem e ela aparecer em um aspecto maior, tipo 90% da minha tela? Sei que é bem simples de fazer. Há vários plugins de lightbox que poderiam ser usados.

Comment: +1 Acho que isso independe do tamanho de tela. Na minha experiência, esse é um problema comum, até mesmo um link para abrir a imagem completa em outra aba já ajudaria bastante (mas um lightbox seria melhor com certeza).

Comment: Ah, também acho @mgibsonbr. O LigthBox é simples e ajuda muito a visualização de imagens. Seria legal ter isso por aqui no SOpt. E +1 pro Cigano que levantou essa questão.